# Genymotion not starting virtual device using start button but starts using command line

Tags: macos, virtualbox, genymotion

I have a genymotion version 2.5.2 on a newly formatted Mac machine with the latest version 5.0.4 of Virtual box.
I have added a virtual device on genymotion but the problem is that it doesnt start at all. 
Its like the start button isnt getting triggered.

I tried the command line to start the device and it worked perfectly well.

```
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "<virtual device name>"
```

I know this has nothing to do with the network config of Virtual box or anything.

Comment: Could you double check it is selected in the UI before clicking on the start button?

Comment: @pcans Didnt get you. Its selected in UI. Actually we can start it by double clicking as well. So selection is surely happening.